Is the completion of a finite $R$-algebra the same as its completion as a module?
Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ and $(S,\mathfrak{n})$ be commutative Noetherian local rings and let $f:R\to S$ be a local ring homomorphism making $S$ into a module-finite $R$-algebra. There are two completions one can consider on $S$. First, there is the $\mathfrak{n}$-adic completion of $S$ as a local ring, $\hat{S}^{\mathfrak{n}}$ and second, there is its $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion as an $R$-module $\hat{S}^{\mathfrak{m}}$. What is the relation between these two completions? Are they isomorphic? If not, are there assumptions that can be added which guarentee they are isomorphic?
In particular, I am interested in the case that $R$ is a reduced $F$-finite Noetherian local ring (characteristic $p$) and $S=R^{1/p^e}$. That is, is the completion of $R^{1/p^e}$ as an $R$-module isomorphic, as an $R$-module, to its completion as a ring?

Since $R\to S$ is finite and $\mathfrak n$ is finitely generated , we have $\mathfrak n^r\subset \mathfrak mS\subset \mathfrak n$ for some $r$ (for example because $\mathfrak n$ is the only prime ideal containing $\mathfrak m S$, so $\sqrt{\mathfrak mS}=\mathfrak n$). So the $\mathfrak m$- and $\mathfrak n$-adic filtrations are "equivalent" and we have an isomorphism of (topological) $R$-modules $\hat S^{\mathfrak n}, \hat S^{\mathfrak m}$.
